# function overloading involving with templates?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I have several overloaded functions:

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};

template<class T> void f(T a) {}  // function 1
void f(A* p) {}                   // function 2
```

When I call

```
B* b;
f(b); // the function 1 is called other than the 2
```

I expect the version 2 is called. Why not and how to let the version 2 is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You called your function with a child class pointer. The template matches this exactly, while calling function 1 would require a conversion to base pointer. Thus the template call is a better match.

You can explicitly `static_cast` to the base class to force the call of the base-pointer version, or I believe you could use something like `enable_if` to disable the template for children of `A`.

Comment: Now I understand. How to work around to let it call the version 2?

Comment: @StoryTeller Of course.  This is one of the simplest and most classical cases of meta-programming.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler selects the best overload it can see.  Type
deduction instantiates your template as `f(B*)`, and that's
clearly a better overload than `f(A*)`.  The usual solution for
this is something like:

```
void f( A* p )
{
}

template <typename T>
void doF( T a, A const* )
{
    f( static_cast<A*>( a ) );
}

template <typename T>
void doF( T a... )
{
    //  your current template implementation
}

template <typename T>
void f( T a )
{
    doF<T>( a, 42 );
}

template <typename T>
void f( T* a )
{
    doF<T*>( a, static_cast<T*>( 0 ) );
}
```

The above works because for non-pointer types, the only function
which can be called is the first template above, which will end
up in your template implementation.  For pointer types, the last
template is more specialized, and so will be a better match
(unless the pointer is `A*`, in which case, the non-template
function will be called); it will pass a null pointer of type
`T*` to `doF`.  If `T*` converts implicitly to an A*, the first
`doF` is the better match; otherwise, the first `doF` cannot be
called, and so the second will be called.